# AttributeError: module 'numpy.lib' has no attribute '_datasource'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently in the very early stages of developing a code on Python that allows the user to view animations of hydrodynamic simulations (protoplanetary discs and other objects), combining a software that does said simulations with matplotlib.animate. I was just playing around in a .py file and managed to make an animation, but since I updated my Numpy version (1.24.3 to 1.25.0) I'm getting an error that I didn't get before.

This is part of the code that I have, first I import the required libraries, and then I load the data from the hydrodynamic simulations with Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

path = '/home/anto/Documents/Codes/public/outputs/fargo/'

phi = np.loadtxt(path + "domain_x.dat")[:-1]
r = np.loadtxt(path + "domain_y.dat")[3:-4]
```

This used to run just fine, but now I'm getting the following message when trying to use `np.loadtxt`:

`AttributeError: module 'numpy.lib' has no attribute '_datasource'`

Also for the record, the Python version I'm currently using is 3.9.7.

This is my first time asking a question on this forum, so I may not know how to do it well. If more info is needed, I will gladly provide it. Thanks!

Comment: That's puzzling, since `loadtxt` works just fine on my newly installed `1.25`.  And `np.lib._datasource` points to a `site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py` file.